# How to interpret the Random Forest Explainer package's mean conditional min depth?

Tags: r, random-forest

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the output from the Random Forest Explainer package's mean conditional minimal depth plot.

The vignette states: *This calculates the mean conditional minimal depth with respect to a vector of variables. It outputs a data frame with each observation giving the means of conditional minimal depth and the size of sample for a given interaction.*

The data frame includes columns such as: mean_min_depth and occurrences.

I was hoping someone could explain, in somewhat plain English, what these terms mean exactly?

Also, I have included a plot of the mean minimal depth (used on the Boston housing dataset) below. What do the 'unconditional' black bars mean?

Code used:

```
forest.boston <- randomForest(medv ~ ., data = Boston, ntree = 100)
MDI.boston <- min_depth_interactions(forest.boston, c("lstat", "rm"))
plot_min_depth_interactions(MDI.boston)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: mean min depth]

Comment: You may find section 6 of this paper of interest: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07196.pdf